# meaning of 'bit'

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is from [a webpage](https://www.billboard.com/music/awards/2022-oscars-producer-will-packer-talks-will-smith-smack-chris-rock-1235053468/).

> Like many of us at home, Will Packer thought the confrontation between
> Will Smith and Chris Rock at Sunday’s 2022 Academy Awards was a **bit**.

I wonder what 'bit' means here.

Does it mean 'a usually short theatrical routine' as defined in the [Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bit)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use is probably the second definition of "bit" in oxford dictionary:

> INFORMAL
>
> a set of actions or ideas associated with a specific group or activity.
>
> "Miranda could go off and do her theatrical bit"

So in this case, this might imply that the confrontation was a joke.

Answer (score 2):

In comedy, a "bit" is a joke or a premise for a joke. In this case, if Will Smith and Chris Rock had planned and then acted out the whole confrontation, then the whole series of events would have constituted a single "bit".